# How to mark a apache ant build as unstable if there are failures

Tags: ant

I have a problem where I can't directly use "fail" ant task in my script. Because it will fail the build.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d64gB.png

I want something in ant script instead of directly fails, it will mark the build as unstable.
Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

"Unstable" is not part of Ant's vocabulary. Ant builds either fail or succeed. I'm guessing you're using Jenkins, in which case you can have Ant `<echo>` a message to the console and then use the text finder plugin to mark the build as unstable if it sees that message.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin